# Export post another site

Tags: posts

I need to migrate a `WP_POST`-type data load to another site.
That site already has data, so I need to make sure there are no `ID` conflicts on the site.
These are the items need to import, using a MySQL query:

- Tables: `WP_POST` AND `WP_POSTMETA`.
- Columns: `ID` AND `Post_ID`...

Comment: Have you tried WP's import/export tools, or an importing plugin?

Comment: thanks for the feedback, but if you already have content on the site it will not conflict with ID